# How to align web parts on a page?

Tags: 2010, search, css

I simply want a **content editor (textbox)** just below the search bar but I can only get it to either go full width or align left. Note that I **don't want to have the text centered, just the box**.

I've tried fixed width - this keeps it on the left. Also tried to add a new web part zone to this page but the option is greyed out, regardless of where I try to insert.

I've also had no luck trying to add custom css (this just breaks it completely). I **have full access to everything including the SharePoint Designer**.

[image: Content Editor needs to be centered]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by randomly dragging around some of the divs in the Sharepoint Editor. It's kind of broken now and won't let me add anything else to the page or make any further layout changes without all the webparts becoming corrupt, but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a table on the page and you can add the CEWP in one of the columns. You can fix the width of the column so that the CEWP is exactly below the search box. Good luck!

Comment: I tried this already but when inserting a webpart into the table, it split the table into two and I was left with a full width content editor again!